# math sqrt function. What am I missing

Tags: c#, sqrt

```
//Add comments here that explain the Sqrt method
        private void btnSqrt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double num = double.Parse(textDisplay.Text);
            if (num >= 0)
            {
                textDisplay.Text = SquareRoot(num).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Number must be positive", "Error Message");
                textDisplay.Text = "0";
            }
        }

        //Add comments here that explain the Sqrt function
        //What are the arguments and the return value(s)

        //To Do – Add the math sqrt method.

        private double SquareRoot(double x)
        {



            textDisplay.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(x)));


        }
```

I having trouble with the math sqrt method.
For this question I have been giving the first line
 private double SquareRoot(double x)
I attempted to write the method but I there is a red line under SquareRoot.
whats wrong with my method?
Thanks
Its a calculator

Comment: You should learn to look closer at the help VS provides before coming here! It certainly told you your method is missing the return value your promised in the signature.

Answer (score 1):

Your method specifies it returns a `double` value, but there is no return statement in its body. To remedy this error, change your method to the following:

```
private double SquareRoot(double x)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(x);
}
```

I removed the `Convert.ToDouble` seeing as your parameter has type `double`, also removed the `Convert.ToString` because you're already calling `ToString` earlier where the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a return statement like this:

```
private double SquareRoot(double x)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(x);
}
```

... or make it `void` ... like this:

```
 private void SquareRoot(double x)
```

Comment: You're calling `Math.Sqrt` and `Convert.ToDouble` twice. The `Convert.ToDouble` is not even needed, because the parameter is already of type `double`.

Comment: @Wazner, yes, I was in the process of editing it.  Could you undown vote me?

Comment: No problem, I removed my downvote. Good job on the quick edit :)

Comment: @Wazner, Thanks!  I noticed before I added an answer, there were zero answers, when I submitted, there were three!

Comment: the name CMath does not exist in the current context

Comment: you were used two brackets at the end of Sqrt

Answer (score 0):

Your method should `return` a `double`, and shouldn't change the `textbox` property.

```
private double SquareRoot(double x)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the value

```
private double SquareRoot(double x)
{
   return Math.Sqrt(x);
}
```